# How can Racer travel great distance in short amount of time?

Tags: fairy-tail

Sawyer, aka Racer of the Oracion Seis is shown to be very fast in melee combat and seems to almost teleport.

However, later his power is explained to be

> Slowing Magic: a time-affecting Magic, changing the way its targets perceive time, and thus making it appear for them that Sawyer is moving around at unholy speed, allowing him to attack freely before they get a chance to counter. Thus objects originating from outside his range keep their original speed.

How does he then travel great distances in short amount of time, the most prominent example being,

> Brain ordering him to retrieve a casket which contains Jellal's body.

How does he travel such great distances?

Answer (score 2):

There's no evidence that might suggest he travels at amazing speed. As you said he just tricks people, that's his power.
However, it is also mentioned he always wanted to be the fastest and trained for that purpose so it would make sense for him to be fast.
We know he's asked to retrieve Jellal but we don't know if he's super fast doing it. The dude might just be the fastest one in Oration Six so that's why he's asked.

Comment: So, he's more or less using star-trek warping, not really moving fast himself, but warping the space around him and moving thru it :P (I had to try and bring startrek to a fairytail fight)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your example, Racer demonstrated the magic to conjure up motorcycles. It's very possible that he rode on a motorbike the whole way, and simply left it when he arrived.

Besides, maybe his natural speed is already fast. Mages in the FT universe have been proven to have above-average physical abilities.

http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Sawyer